# hot to use python diff html

Tags: python, html, diff

is there a way diff html as bellow ?

```
html_1 = "<h1>text<h1>"
html_2 = "<h2>text<h2>"
```

use google's `diff_prettyHtml` will not work correctly .
i will say that `1` change to `2`:

```
<h
<del style="background:#ffe6e6;">1</del>
<ins style="background:#e6ffe6;">2</ins>
>sadfasdf</h
<del style="background:#ffe6e6;">1</del>
<ins style="background:#e6ffe6;">2</ins>
>
```

but i want so say `<h1>text<h1>` change to `<h2>text<h2>` :

```
<del style="background:#ffe6e6;"><h1>text<h1></del>
<ins style="background:#e6ffe6;"><h2>text<h2></ins>
```

how could i do it ? is there any python libary do it ?

Comment: You want something which diffs the rendered output of html?  I don't know of any such tool, because html is such a mess that two pages which render identically can be completely different at the source level.  Also different browsers can render the same html differently.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by diff specifically? What should this diff feature output and take in? Does Pygments do the trick? It is a syntax highlighter that can highlight differences.

http://pygments.org/